# how to use character vector select object in r

Tags: r

I struggled with this problem for a long time. Say, I have 2 plots and want to export them using `ggexport()`.

```
library(ggplot2)

p1 <- qplot(data = mtcars, x = cyl)
p2 <- qplot(data = mtcars, x = cyl, y = mpg)

plot_list <- list(p1, p2)
ggexport(plotlist = plot_list, filename = 'test.pdf')
```

Now I have many of plots named `p1`,`p2`,`p3`...`p100` and I don't want to type them one by one, so I use `paste0()` (at this example I only paste `p1` and `p2`)

```
plot_list <- list(paste0('p',1:2))
```

It's just a character vector in `plot_list`, not the plots. I searched for some methods and tried but all failed.

```
plot_list <- list(parse(paste0('p',1:2)))

plot_list <- list(eval(parse(paste0('p',1:2))))

plot_list <- list(syms(paste0('p',1:2)))

# only one plot in it
plot_list <- list(get(paste0('p',1:2)))
```

Could someone tell me how to do this or support some reference. I think I have a lot of deficiencies in the object name selecting and using.

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: `plot_list <- mget(paste0('p',1:2))`

Answer (score 1):

Using `lapply` to apply the `get` on your character vector of plot names does the trick of returning a list of plots

```
plot_list <- lapply(paste0('p',1:2), get)
```